# Using function if, if condition is true, not working?

Tags: c

I want so that when the user enters `e` it will run my function called enter and scan in values but all I get is `VECRQ?:`, why is this? Did I call upon the function wrong?

I tried having the while loop to `1` also instead of `menuoption != 'q'` didn't work. I was thinking that with the `menuoption` is not equal to `'q'` it will keep the loop running until the user actually enters `'q'` to shut the program off.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int enter(int measurments[], int nrOfmeasurments)
{
    while(nrOfmeasurments<10) 
    {
        printf("Enter measurment #%d (or q to quit): ",nrOfmeasurments+1);
        int oneMeasurment;
        int readInteger = scanf("%d",&oneMeasurment);
        if(readInteger)
        {
            measurments[nrOfmeasurments] = oneMeasurment;
            nrOfmeasurments ++;
            //return nrOfmeasurments;
        }
        else
        {
            char tmp;
            scanf(" %c",&tmp);
            break;
        }

    }
    if(nrOfmeasurments==10)
    {
        printf("Array is full\n");
    }

    return nrOfmeasurments;
}

int main(void)
{
    int measurments[10];
    int nrOfmeasurments;
    char menuoption;
    printf("Measurment tool 2.0\n");

    while (menuoption != 'q')
    {
        printf("VECRQ?:\n");
        scanf(" %c",&menuoption);

        if (menuoption == 'e')
        {
            //int MeasurmentData[10];
            //int nrOfmeasurments;
            //enter(measurments, nrOfmeasurments);
            nrOfmeasurments = enter(measurments, nrOfmeasurments);
        }
        else if(menuoption == 'v')
        {

        }
        else if(menuoption == 'c')
        {

        }
        else if(menuoption == 'q')
        {
            printf("Exiting Measurment tool 2.0\n");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just compiled the `main` function of your code, with the call to the `enter` function commented out. I entered `q` and the output read `"Exiting Measurment tool 2.0"` and the program terminated. So, unless you pasted the wrong code for `main`, it would appear that the `enter` function is exhibiting unexpected behavior or something else is going on (i.e. you're compiling an old source file).

Comment: i'm sure that i am using a newly saved file, should i maybe save it as another name?

Comment: okay the wrong was that i didnt declare in the main that the nrOfmeasurments = 0;

Comment: That's probably not the problem. Have a look at your code at this online C IDE - [https://onlinegdb.com/SJC5UC5vH](https://onlinegdb.com/SJC5UC5vH) - click the green run button and enter `q`, the program will output goodbye message and terminate. Can you [edit] your question and include exactly what you're inputting while the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to init your variables with default values. Your problem is that `nrOfmeasurments` is not initialized and have some trash value. Also, set a default value to `menuoption` for some non `q` char to be sure, that your loop will be executed at least one time

Comment: Since the loop is left on `q` anyway, there is no need for `while(...)`. Simply replace it by `for (;;)`. Then you don't need to initialise `menuoption` because it will be set by `scanf()`. But this is not quite exact: Of course you have to check the return value of `scanf()`!

Comment: @thebusybee But it's still a good idea to initialize all variables with a default value

Comment: No, it isn't. A double write without a read in between is a bad code smell. Most serious problem: It shows that the author does **not** know what she does. Additional problems include wasted code space, increased run time, and/or variable space.

Comment: But your code can be changed in the future and you simply can forget, that variable was not initialized and it will create a lot more problems, that wasted code space

Comment: Then still it holds true that the author does **not** know what she's doing. My compiler and (if the compiler isn't capable enough) my static code analyzer will warn me. Use the tools, don't fight them!